# How to remove extra space in global-linum-mode?

Tags: emacs

Having global-linum-mode on creates extra space on the left hand.
How do I get rid of this extra space and just show the line numbers?

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space that appears on the left side of the buffer when global-linum-mode is enabled is caused by the default linum-format setting, which adds a certain amount of padding to the line numbers to make sure they align properly.

To get rid of the extra space and just show the line numbers without any padding, you can customize the linum-format variable. This variable determines the format of the line numbers in global-linum-mode, and you can set it to a format string that doesn't include any padding.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(linum-format "%d"))
```